# Using AngularJS with MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, meteor

So I am fairly new to both of these technologies. My plan was to implement the Peepcode Tunes project that they made with Backbone ( https://github.com/philipkobernik/backbone-tunes ) with MeteorJS and then try implementing it using MeteorJS with the AngularJS addon. Someone has already done it all in just Angular: https://github.com/angular/peepcode-tunes

Most things went pretty smoothly. You can see what I have so far at:

Just Meteor: https://github.com/Jonovono/Meteor-peepcode-tunes
Meteor and AngularJs: https://github.com/Jonovono/Meteor-angular-peepcode-tunes

I really enjoy working with Angular and being able to pass things from the view like:

```
ng-click="pl.add(album)">
```

Which seems more complicated when just using Meteor.

However one question I am having. Say I want to save the playlist every time a album is added/removed. So that if the page is refreshed it still is there. I don't know the best way to do this and when using AngularJS with Meteor I am confused how this should be done.

Right now when using Angular and Meteor I do something like this:

```
$scope.Playlist = new Meteor.AngularCollection("playlist", $scope);
$scope.playlist = $scope.Playlist.findOne({});

    $scope.pl.add = function(album) {
    if ($scope.playlist.indexOf(album) != -1) return;
    $scope.playlist.push(album);
    $scope.playlist.$save();
};
```

However that does not seem to save it to the database. But if I were to do something like:

```
    album.title = "CHANGED"
    album.$save()
```

It seems like it would save this to the database.

I am sure I am just missing something small in regards to Meteor or the AngularJS add on to it. Any enlightenment would be awesome!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Creator of the bridge here. Did you pull the latest version from github? I haven't updated the  version on atmosphere yet. Sorry for that . .findOne needs some extra code will push it this evening.

https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs

Comment: Sweet. I will check that out soon. Thanks for putting that together. I have found it really helpful in learning Angular and Meteor!

Comment: @Jonovono findOne has been added, check out the github page & the example, if you have more questions just ask.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. I just tried it out and I did not change anything and am now getting an error  Cannot call method 'find' of undefined in my browser console when I run  

    `$scope.Albums = new Meteor.AngularCollection("albums", $scope);
 $scope.albums = $scope.Albums.find({});  `

Maybe I should put this on Github, but heres my project: https://github.com/Jonovono/Meteor-angular-peepcode-tunes . I'll keep trying it out but got to run out right away.

Comment: Hi, You can fix this error by not doing new Meteor.collection on the client-side. I do have committed a fix for that issue.

Comment: Awesome! Seems to be working!  Thanks a lot. I will likely have more questions in the future so see you on github.

Answer (score 2):

Creator of the new bridge here :)

As the old bridge is no longer maintained our team wrote and is actively maintaining this library - [angular-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor) and we've also released a tutorial for combining the two - [angular-meteor tutorial](http://angularjs.meteor.com/tutorial)

Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

u can use angular meteor as Uri mentioned
+ u can see more angular modules that are available
[angular modules](https://atmospherejs.com/angularjs)