# AngularJs and Meteor integration

Tags: angularjs, meteor, javascript-framework

In the short time I've worked with angular I've found it's pretty cool. Now I run into Meteor and like everybody I'm very excited about it. I'm starting a few personal projects with angular and I would like to integrate them with meteor as well.
What is the best way to bring both frameworks working together?

*Note:* I found [Meteor_angularjs](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs), is it developed by either Angular or Meteor Developers or just "a cool guy making my day"? I saw one youtube video where AngularJs members speak of their plans about meteor integration, is this related?

**Edit:** The question is about how to integrate both frameworks, right now the only option available is Lander Van Breda's solution so I thank him and I will take that option as my answer but since both parties have demonstrated interest in integrating their frameworks with each other it would be nice to hear from them and see what their official implementations are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using AngularJS with MeteorJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150826/using-angularjs-with-meteorjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the question about? Is it from Angular or Meteor? No, it's from @LanderVanBreda, so I guess it from "a cool guy making your day" (and mine also, btw).

Meteor has some plans for angular (and alike) in their ["Wishlist"](https://trello.com/card/examples-demonstrating-angular-ember-backbone-integrations/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/66)

I really hope angular + meteor really takes off, but for now it's up to Lander Van Breda to keep us up-to-date with his [Meteor_angularjs](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs) since he is the only one maintaining it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm obviously biased but our team wrote and is actively maintaining this library - [angular-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor) and we've also released a tutorial for combining the two - [angular-meteor tutorial](http://angularjs.meteor.com/tutorial)

Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample of meteor leaderboard in angular that use lvbreda package, it could help

https://github.com/bevanhunt/meteor-angular-leaderboard